# If $f$ is an odd function then $c_n = 0$ for $n$ even

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that the analytic function $f$ has a power series expansion
> $\sum c_n z^n$.
>
> Show that if $f$ is an odd function then $c_n = 0$ for $n$ even.

Attempt:

$f$ is odd $\rightarrow $ $\\f(-z) = - f(z) \rightarrow f(z) + f(-z) = 0 \\\rightarrow \sum c_n z^n + \sum (-1)^nc_n z^n = 0 \\\rightarrow 2\sum\limits_{k\geq 0}c_{2k}z^{2k} = 0 \\\rightarrow c_{2k} = 0 \;\;\forall \;k \geq 0$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you for confirming.

Comment: What makes you think that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{2k}z^{2k}=0\implies(\forall k\in\Bbb Z^+):c_{2k}=0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Identity theorem

Comment: Then you could as well apply it to$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kc_kz^k.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what would be the accumulation point here. In my post I am applying identity theorem with $0$ being an accumulation point.

Comment: Here, it would be $0$ too.